# Convert a decimal number saved in an array into a binary number saved in an array, and vice versa

Tags: c, arrays, binary, decimal

I've been researching ways to convert a decimal number to a binary number. However in the examples I find the decimal number to be converted is not within an array.
For example:

```
void decToBinary(int n) 
{ 
    // array to store binary number 
    int binaryNum[32]; 

    // counter for binary array 
    int i = 0; 
    while (n > 0) { 

        // storing remainder in binary array 
        binaryNum[i] = n % 2; 
        n = n / 2; 
        i++; 
    } 
}
```

In my case, however, I have a decimal number saved in an array uint8_t* (randomly generated) how could you pass it to a binary number saved in an array? And then, how could I pass it back to decimal number saved in an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return the `binaryNum` because it's local variable. But firstly, you have to revert the array for exact binary number:

```
uint8_t * returArray;
returArray = malloc(sizeof(int) * i);

for(int j = i - 1, k = 0; j >= 0; j--, k++) {
    returArray[j] = binaryNum[k];
}
```

The function becomes as:

```
uint8_t * decToBinary(int n, int *size) 
{ 
    // array to store binary number 
    int binaryNum[32];
    uint8_t * returArray;

    // counter for binary array 
    int i = 0; 
    while (n > 0) { 

        // storing remainder in binary array 
        binaryNum[i] = n % 2; 
        n = n / 2; 
        i++; 
    } 

    returArray = malloc(sizeof(int) * i);
    if (!returArray)
       // handle error;

    for(int j = i - 1, k = 0; j >= 0; j--, k++) {
        returArray[j] = binaryNum[k];
    }
    *size = i;
    return returArray;
}
```

`size` value is the size of binary array.

The main for test:

```
int main(void) {
    int size;
    uint8_t * a = decToBinary(25, &size);
    printf("size = %d\n", size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d", a[i]);
    }
    free(a);
    return 0;
}
```

If you want to convert back to decimal, you need to do something invert the way you convert decimal to binary:

```
int main() {
   ...
   int decimal = 0;
   int base = 1;
   for (int i = size-1; i >= 0; i--)
   {
       decimal += base * a[i];
       base *= 2;
   }
}
```

Update for converting all value in array:

```
uint8_t * converAll(int * decimalArr, int size, int *new_size) {
    uint8_t * returArray = malloc(sizeof(uint8_t));
    if(! returArray) {
        // handle error
    }
    int bsize;
    int temp = 0, k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
       uint8_t *arr = decToBinary(decimalArr[i], &bsize);
       returArray = realloc(returArray ,sizeof(uint8_t) * (bsize + temp));
       if(! returArray) {
        // handle error
       }
       for (int j = 0; j < bsize; j++) {
            returArray[k] = arr[j];
            k++;
       }
       temp += bsize;
    }
    *new_size = k;

    return returArray;
}
```

This function can be used as:

```
int arr[] = {3,6,3,8,9,4};
uint8_t * a = converAll(arr, 6,  &size);
```

Comment: In my case I don't receive a decimal number n directly because I have the decimal number stored in an array. How could the function change this?

Comment: Do you want to convert all decimal numbers in input array or just one value in the array ?

Comment: For example if I have array x that contains {3,6,3,8,9,4} i want to obtain the binary 1011000110101110110

Comment: Alternatively, declare the array in main and pass it as a parameter to avoid the malloc/free.

Comment: @Marc you can create the function that content the loop for concatenating all binary

Comment: @stark what do you mean, sorry, can you explain your idea more ?

Comment: @Marc i create a example for your case, it's not optimized but you can use it for the idea of concatenation the binary numbers

Comment: Thanks, As I observe in the example the conversion from binary to decimal, the obtained decimal number is stored in an int, how could it be saved in an uint8_t * array?

Comment: let's replace int by uint8_t. But be careful with the decimal value that you want to convert. it will be up to 255.